# Locating text that contains a certain string with space?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am having a problem locate text containing at least two words.

I need the next one:

```xml
<a e="k44.3" href="http://www.example.com">hello world</a>
```

and my XPath expression is:

```java
driv.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'hello world')]")).click();
```

But XPath took only the first word (output) from console:

```xml
  <a e="k77.4" href="http://www.example.com">hello</a>
```

How can I select the the one with the 'hello world'?

Comment: I'm sure your XPath expression is correct. Could you show us more HTML? How many links do you have on the page?

Comment: Your XPath should return the element on top, but not the one on the bottom. See [demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/6815b6789f5d54259638f3fe799e8f74)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following and let me know if it not works:

```
driv.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='hello world']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
Driver.findElement(By.linkText("hello world"));
```

This will click on the links containing spaces also.